# iOS implementing NETunnelProviderProtocol with no remote server

Tags: ios, vpn, ios-extensions

I'm trying to implement a packet sniffer similar to [Charles for iOS](https://www.charlesproxy.com/ios/) using iOS's NetworkExtension framework.

#### Objective

So, that's a big goal and I'm breaking it down into a tiny piece right now: I want to see the `os_log` from my `NEPacketTunnelProvider` (bottom box in diagram)

[image]

#### What I have done so far

1. I have created a NetworkExtension target on type PacketTunnel. This is the code snippet in the 3rd box in the diagram titled "NEPacketTunnelProvider".
2. I have included the "app groups", "personal VPN", and "Network extension" capabilities from within XCode.

#### Question

I am looking in the Console.app to see the output from `os_log("STARTING TUNNEL!!!!")`. When I load the configuration and make the call to `startVPNTunnel()`, why is my TunnelProvider code never called?

I have verified that `startVPNTunnel()` is being called by placing a breakpoint in my code.

Comment: Have you achieved this local Tunnel Provider?

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you manage to find a solution? All my entitlements are setup right, im looking at logs in Console.app. I added Sandbox to my entitlements (both) with value YES. Still can not get the NEPacketTunnelProvider subclasses override startTunnel to log

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a good number of reasons why your network extension process may not be starting:

1. I would put a breakpoint on the `os_log("STARTING TUNNEL!!!!")` and attach to your network extension process in Xcode via `Debug -> Attach to Process by PID or Name...` before you attempt to start the VPN
2. The network extension must extend the bundle id of the containing app. E.g. if the containing app is `com.example.vpn` then the network extension might be `com.example.vpn.tunnel`.
3. Ensure that your Network Extension `Info.plist` contains the `NSExtension` dictionary with `NSExtensionPointIdentifier` and `NSExtensionPrincipalClass` containing `com.apple.networkextension.packet-tunnel` and your `NEPacketTunnelProvider` class (e.g. `$(PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME).PacketTunnelProvider`) respectively.
4. Is the Packet Tunnel Provider Network Extension entitlement applied to both the containing application and the network extension?
5. If you are implementing a Packet Tunnel Provider, you do not want to enable the `Personal VPN` entitlement.

Comment: I actually learned that there was a license agreement that somebody on the team had to accept before I could use the extension, but there was no error thrown. That said, this is a really useful checklist, so I'll accept in case anybody is having issues in the future. Thanks!

Comment: Hey @wheresmycookie may you help in same case  my startTunnel is also not calling in extension

Comment: @AbhimanyuRathore can you provide more information? What have you tried and what issues do you currently have?

Comment: Dear @wheresmycookie first of all thanks for response. I created an app with packet tunnel extension and followed all 2 app ids instructions ant set everything . but my extension "startTunnel" is not calling :( I am trying to connect a IKEv2 Server ( which is connected with NEVPNManager ) successfully. also loaded Configuration Profile in iPad Successfully by apple's guideline:-   https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension/netunnelprovidermanager

Comment: VPN Status is stuck in "Connecting"  rather than "Connected" :(

Comment: there I want your support to convert this in to connected + StartTunnel Call

Answer (score 1):

in startVPNTunnel  func ,you should call setTunnelNetworkSettings,then the tunnel will started, after that ,you can read/write packet.

```html
setTunnelNetworkSettings(nil) {  error in
            pendingStartCompletion(error)
            
 }
```