# NEPacketTunnelProvider crashing with ambiguous error message

Tags: ios

I'm [working on adding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56619465/ios-implementing-netunnelproviderprotocol-with-no-remote-server) a NEPacketTunnelProvider to my app to write a custom VPN client.

I describe in more detail in the linked post the exact code and setup, but in this question I would just like to understand this error report and what it might be indicating:

```
Incident Identifier: 989DBEC9-63B4-4D7B-BA7E-B12FFA9310D1
CrashReporter Key:   781c0b0ec899d57bf9ca9ad04706c4b851b8a121
Hardware Model:      iPhone7,2
Process:             CustomTunnel [5071]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/0694B5BD-9C8F-408B-96C2-3DAFEE9052D4/ScreentimeSolver.app/PlugIns/CustomTunnel.appex/CustomTunnel
Identifier:          io.XXX.ScreentimeSolver.CustomTunnel
Version:             1 (1.0)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Unspecified
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           io.XXX.ScreentimeSolver.CustomTunnel [2711]


Date/Time:           2019-06-16 19:05:26.2590 +0200
Launch Time:         2019-06-16 19:05:25.9636 +0200
OS Version:          iPhone OS 12.3.1 (16F203)
Baseband Version:    7.70.01
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  2

Application Specific Information:
abort() called

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x1a655127c __exceptionPreprocess + 228
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x1a572b9f8 objc_exception_throw + 55
2   CoreFoundation                  0x1a64cace8 _CFThrowFormattedException + 111
3   CoreFoundation                  0x1a643fb18 -[__NSDictionaryM setObject:forKey:] + 939
4   Foundation                      0x1a6f6eed4 -[_NSExtensionContextVendor _setPrincipalObject:forUUID:] + 99
5   Foundation                      0x1a6f6e744 __105-[_NSExtensionContextVendor _beginRequestWithExtensionItems:listenerEndpoint:withContextUUID:completion:]_block_invoke + 763
6   libdispatch.dylib               0x1a5f90a38 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 23
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x1a5f917d4 _dispatch_client_callout + 15
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x1a5f3a320 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain$VARIANT$mp + 591
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x1a5f3ae3c _dispatch_lane_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 427
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x1a5f434a8 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 595
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x1a6171114 _pthread_wqthread + 303
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x1a6173cd4 start_wqthread + 3


Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001a60e30f4 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001a60e25a0 mach_msg + 72
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a64e2a10 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 236
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a64dd920 __CFRunLoopRun + 1360
4   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a64dd0b0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436
5   Foundation                      0x00000001a6eaafac -[NSRunLoop+ 32684 (NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 300
6   Foundation                      0x00000001a6ee646c -[NSRunLoop+ 275564 (NSRunLoop) run] + 88
7   libxpc.dylib                    0x00000001a61b0a44 _xpc_objc_main + 516
8   libxpc.dylib                    0x00000001a61b33a4 xpc_main + 176
9   Foundation                      0x00000001a6ee8400 +[NSXPCListener serviceListener] + 0
10  PlugInKit                       0x00000001ac01b328 0x1ac009000 + 74536
11  PlugInKit                       0x00000001ac01b154 0x1ac009000 + 74068
12  PlugInKit                       0x00000001ac01b6a4 0x1ac009000 + 75428
13  Foundation                      0x00000001a70b7a18 NSExtensionMain + 64
14  libdyld.dylib                   0x00000001a5fa28e0 start + 4

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001a6173cd0 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 2 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.extension.global-state-queue
Thread 2 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001a60ee0dc __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001a6167094 pthread_kill$VARIANT$mp + 380
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00000001a6047ea8 abort + 140
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001a5714788 __cxa_bad_cast + 0
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001a5714934 default_unexpected_handler+ 6452 () + 0
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001a572be00 _objc_terminate+ 24064 () + 124
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001a5720838 std::__terminate(void (*)+ 55352 ()) + 16
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001a57208c4 std::terminate+ 55492 () + 84
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001a5f917e8 _dispatch_client_callout + 36
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001a5f3a320 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain$VARIANT$mp + 592
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001a5f3ae3c _dispatch_lane_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 428
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001a5f434a8 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 596
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001a6171114 _pthread_wqthread + 304
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001a6173cd4 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 2 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000000000000   x1: 0x0000000000000000   x2: 0x0000000000000000   x3: 0x0000000117e21f17
    x4: 0x00000001a5723b71   x5: 0x000000016f73a460   x6: 0x000000000000006e   x7: 0xffffffffffffffec
    x8: 0x0000000000000c00   x9: 0x00000001a616b888  x10: 0x00000001a6166f18  x11: 0x0000000000000003
   x12: 0x0000000000000000  x13: 0x0000010000000000  x14: 0x0000000000000010  x15: 0x0000000000000000
   x16: 0x0000000000000148  x17: 0x0000000000000000  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000000000006
   x20: 0x000000016f73b000  x21: 0x000000016f73a460  x22: 0x0000000000002103  x23: 0x000000016f73b0e0
   x24: 0x0000000101400840  x25: 0x0000000000000000  x26: 0x0000000000000000  x27: 0x0000000000000000
   x28: 0x000000016f73b0e0   fp: 0x000000016f73a3c0   lr: 0x00000001a6167094
    sp: 0x000000016f73a390   pc: 0x00000001a60ee0dc cpsr: 0x00000000

Binary Images:
0x1007d8000 - 0x1007dffff CustomTunnel arm64  <6671f6b480533ceaa1b0f53a527caf04> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/0694B5BD-9C8F-408B-96C2-3DAFEE9052D4/ScreentimeSolver.app/PlugIns/CustomTunnel.appex/CustomTunnel
0x1007f0000 - 0x1007f7fff libswiftCoreFoundation.dylib arm64  <47deeaa1967b3e339dfcb48535a994e1> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/0694B5BD-9C8F-408B-96C2-3DAFEE9052D4/ScreentimeSolver.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreFoundation.dylib
0x100804000 - 0x10085bfff dyld arm64  <9c893b6aa3b13d9596326ef6952e7195> /usr/lib/dyld
0x1008c4000 - 0x100bfbfff libswiftCore.dylib arm64  <a6ddef6199143f14876bac3d281b4cfe> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/0694B5BD-9C8F-408B-96C2-3DAFEE9052D4/ScreentimeSolver.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib
0x100f00000 - 0x100f0ffff libswiftCoreGraphics.dylib arm64  <25fe91aa901b3cf6a443b498012ab5af> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/0694B5BD-9C8F-408B-96C2-3DAFEE9052D4/ScreentimeSolver.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreGraphics.dylib
0x100f34000 - 0x100f3ffff libswiftDarwin.dylib arm64  <b430370f979638fea97ab26a84bcb5d6> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/0694B5BD-9C8F-408B-96C2-3DAFEE9052D4/ScreentimeSolver.app/Frameworks/libswiftDarwin.dylib
0x100f54000 - 0x100f6ffff libswiftDispatch.dylib arm64  <7ad01fe8bf9f3bad811e9c5ce8c68f8f> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/0694B5BD-9C8F-408B-96C2-3DAFEE9052D4/ScreentimeSolver.app/Frameworks/libswiftDispatch.dylib
0x100fb0000 - 0x1010fffff libswiftFoundation.dylib arm64  <0848e6ddbbfb31ae87c86b45ff691470> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/0694B5BD-9C8F-408B-96C2-3DAFEE9052D4/ScreentimeSolver.app/Frameworks/libswiftFoundation.dylib
0x1012b4000 - 0x1012bbfff libswiftObjectiveC.dylib arm64  <ec73a6a65788317397cc32bbd09d8fbd> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/0694B5BD-9C8F-408B-96C2-3DAFEE9052D4/ScreentimeSolver.app/Frameworks/libswiftObjectiveC.dylib
0x1012cc000 - 0x1012fbfff libswiftSwiftOnoneSupport.dylib arm64  <56cdea7acd713d499d5452b9ebeaa83e> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/0694B5BD-9C8F-408B-96C2-3DAFEE9052D4/ScreentimeSolver.app/Frameworks/libswiftSwiftOnoneSupport.dylib
0x101338000 - 0x10133ffff libswiftos.dylib arm64  <8e3b4ee77a833c3fad9499717ed18eec> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/0694B5BD-9C8F-408B-96C2-3DAFEE9052D4/ScreentimeSolver.app/Frameworks/libswiftos.dylib
0x1a56bb000 - 0x1a56bcfff libSystem.B.dylib arm64  <2d9d93c74687353281fc2f486a371680> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
0x1a56bd000 - 0x1a5712fff libc++.1.dylib arm64  <e1843de67f9234e6a7c59cfb6ffe5e76> /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
0x1a5713000 - 0x1a5725fff libc++abi.dylib arm64  <b2407b2b53073779b86b8765c6ea72c2> /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
0x1a5726000 - 0x1a5eadfff libobjc.A.dylib arm64  <c48d66667b893a29959044bb49a1973e> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
0x1a5eae000 - 0x1a5eb2fff libcache.dylib arm64  <22202d885c35395a9734dc0d7dc02b29> /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib
0x1a5eb3000 - 0x1a5ebefff libcommonCrypto.dylib arm64  <0670536269b63ab289d61f36dd2aa431> /usr/lib/system/libcommonCrypto.dylib
0x1a5ebf000 - 0x1a5ec3fff libcompiler_rt.dylib arm64  <14258a4709af3ffba47a04bc00b9646a> /usr/lib/system/libcompiler_rt.dylib
0x1a5ec4000 - 0x1a5eccfff libcopyfile.dylib arm64  <903036d60844385987e8bec76e22bcad> /usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib
0x1a5ecd000 - 0x1a5f30fff libcorecrypto.dylib arm64  <9f7915fc35b737e880ff06f14f73d523> /usr/lib/system/libcorecrypto.dylib
0x1a5f31000 - 0x1a5fa0fff libdispatch.dylib arm64  <94dcbc89bacb39beadffccea74e7bdb6> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
0x1a5fa1000 - 0x1a5fcafff libdyld.dylib arm64  <39ee943ad0ca301180519d4a1173734f> /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
0x1a5fcb000 - 0x1a5fcbfff liblaunch.dylib arm64  <729cfcd40d393f308cdbb266917306db> /usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib
0x1a5fcc000 - 0x1a5fd1fff libmacho.dylib arm64  <0cc10aed9fe1322fa37cdd01e6c3e771> /usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib
0x1a5fd2000 - 0x1a5fd3fff libremovefile.dylib arm64  <5a2545f357d6342d9641ec17eedebf59> /usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib
0x1a5fd4000 - 0x1a5febfff libsystem_asl.dylib arm64  <40fd59634e5532d49a4f441f37283d0e> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_asl.dylib
0x1a5fec000 - 0x1a5fecfff libsystem_blocks.dylib arm64  <8dd7ed74d37d3dde8eb600edf862c82f> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib
0x1a5fed000 - 0x1a606efff libsystem_c.dylib arm64  <5dcc765a916a3daeb108d6502c377ae4> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
0x1a606f000 - 0x1a6073fff libsystem_configuration.dylib arm64  <99cc1779fbeb371a8dc9971a007cf6e1> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_configuration.dylib
0x1a6074000 - 0x1a607afff libsystem_containermanager.dylib arm64  <b342816916ef3f3e9e22cf2f1544acfd> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_containermanager.dylib
0x1a607b000 - 0x1a607cfff libsystem_coreservices.dylib arm64  <90373e3876e03823a8ed93ea69564b3d> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_coreservices.dylib
0x1a607d000 - 0x1a6083fff libsystem_darwin.dylib arm64  <24fd8e0c02383189a10f80ac34a9755c> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_darwin.dylib
0x1a6084000 - 0x1a608afff libsystem_dnssd.dylib arm64  <1fb1d15c469934529208e8bd6ad41085> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_dnssd.dylib
0x1a608b000 - 0x1a60cafff libsystem_info.dylib arm64  <82fee029e7e039cfbf2b75818cd69028> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib
0x1a60cb000 - 0x1a60f5fff libsystem_kernel.dylib arm64  <cc9f9508b5bf3478a442f3cec1591804> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
0x1a60f6000 - 0x1a6123fff libsystem_m.dylib arm64  <fa8fefc7c2f33c228b635f1526ee1943> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_m.dylib
0x1a6124000 - 0x1a6146fff libsystem_malloc.dylib arm64  <3cf7982226b039749f8eebd3f328c63e> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_malloc.dylib
0x1a6147000 - 0x1a6152fff libsystem_networkextension.dylib arm64  <16d95a4894953f70bdbd6b2e6fa2ada3> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_networkextension.dylib
0x1a6153000 - 0x1a6159fff libsystem_notify.dylib arm64  <3e85f77a7641310c827a7e926a8bf673> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_notify.dylib
0x1a615a000 - 0x1a6164fff libsystem_platform.dylib arm64  <8b5dd1f4cd3c3c99b2911f7290ddf050> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib
0x1a6165000 - 0x1a6175fff libsystem_pthread.dylib arm64  <beb13d8311cd3aa1a18dea822da57c69> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib
0x1a6176000 - 0x1a6178fff libsystem_sandbox.dylib arm64  <1328091ae30237658e045dcbb41772f9> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib
0x1a6179000 - 0x1a6180fff libsystem_symptoms.dylib arm64  <a31d562710bd3d99a1cff7b78de4491a> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_symptoms.dylib
0x1a6181000 - 0x1a6196fff libsystem_trace.dylib arm64  <813eaa7de9753714a813eabaea1e39e2> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_trace.dylib
0x1a6197000 - 0x1a619cfff libunwind.dylib arm64  <e00ff283d08538c1b34675a5e665bcdc> /usr/lib/system/libunwind.dylib
0x1a619d000 - 0x1a61cafff libxpc.dylib arm64  <7047fecf09023c959ca2a8499239f4a2> /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib
0x1a61cb000 - 0x1a6426fff libicucore.A.dylib arm64  <9015b4c283943ee891433bd65535e6bf> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
0x1a6427000 - 0x1a6438fff libz.1.dylib arm64  <869dd3bee3ba3e7abd0cbad2f428cdbc> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
0x1a6439000 - 0x1a6795fff CoreFoundation arm64  <8f67863fa23e377190d7993168740877> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x1a6796000 - 0x1a67a6fff libbsm.0.dylib arm64  <4524c293a9ab3f40bd476f0e665dfc55> /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
0x1a67a7000 - 0x1a67a7fff libenergytrace.dylib arm64  <4733292256c23d85910a258f21770d6c> /usr/lib/libenergytrace.dylib
0x1a67a8000 - 0x1a6836fff IOKit arm64  <8cbd79075b063189808df404fe3ae179> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
0x1a6837000 - 0x1a691efff libxml2.2.dylib arm64  <1b51169d88b436ac8b374a52fc7ee591> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
0x1a691f000 - 0x1a692cfff libbz2.1.0.dylib arm64  <0c1876f0044234339a72c5d1f1ab2c9b> /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib
0x1a692d000 - 0x1a6945fff liblzma.5.dylib arm64  <dbbb8e6e5cd333969343748c303a771d> /usr/lib/liblzma.5.dylib
0x1a6946000 - 0x1a6abffff libsqlite3.dylib arm64  <48776c5c404d3ed589a60f07eb2e995b> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
0x1a6ac0000 - 0x1a6af4fff libMobileGestalt.dylib arm64  <0d11307f9a3e3ddb80779e03e5e6a31c> /usr/lib/libMobileGestalt.dylib
0x1a6af5000 - 0x1a6ea2fff CFNetwork arm64  <f76b7b973d7d306484d1922a6b85d0f8> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
0x1a6ea3000 - 0x1a718dfff Foundation arm64  <25293172df9f3fb99e4ffd4ea250557e> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x1a718e000 - 0x1a729cfff Security arm64  <198a5510ae6c3605898d3b06c7dec3d9> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
0x1a729d000 - 0x1a7306fff SystemConfiguration arm64  <67fe60d5ad553f63a9f973e11e5a9dad> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
0x1a7307000 - 0x1a7339fff libCRFSuite.dylib arm64  <c2a13500b7e33a71b9c36cb6bb890286> /usr/lib/libCRFSuite.dylib
0x1a733a000 - 0x1a7350fff libapple_nghttp2.dylib arm64  <1637a851ff65353888978ec0c4d1e0ac> /usr/lib/libapple_nghttp2.dylib
0x1a7351000 - 0x1a737afff libarchive.2.dylib arm64  <598c101a5eaa3da89ddf37e4a8003757> /usr/lib/libarchive.2.dylib
0x1a7443000 - 0x1a7459fff libcoretls.dylib arm64  <89b2a60485493023b95e8ec9e624c5f7> /usr/lib/libcoretls.dylib
0x1a745a000 - 0x1a745bfff libcoretls_cfhelpers.dylib arm64  <83728d8a332239578fb6ace719b8e0ac> /usr/lib/libcoretls_cfhelpers.dylib
0x1a745c000 - 0x1a745dfff liblangid.dylib arm64  <eb6be37c1f11338088aaf9cc9b08cc6b> /usr/lib/liblangid.dylib
0x1a745e000 - 0x1a77cefff libnetwork.dylib arm64  <c8c1090660d536519b1fad5945225560> /usr/lib/libnetwork.dylib
0x1a77cf000 - 0x1a7802fff libpcap.A.dylib arm64  <ba41e93b1cca3f14847891c4cf5750cf> /usr/lib/libpcap.A.dylib
0x1a7861000 - 0x1a786dfff IOSurface arm64  <24abbc56094a3cdcb452e7e7e58e8ce7> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOSurface.framework/IOSurface
0x1a786e000 - 0x1a7920fff libBLAS.dylib arm64  <1227677a0887399cabb9f71366fe24db> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBLAS.dylib
0x1a7921000 - 0x1a7c3dfff libLAPACK.dylib arm64  <ce98dc1d007d31619daf31c5adac2442> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLAPACK.dylib
0x1a7c3e000 - 0x1a7eacfff vImage arm64  <41f05566962d355e91f4477b4e772f70> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vImage.framework/vImage
0x1a7ead000 - 0x1a7ebefff libSparseBLAS.dylib arm64  <338f8bc90d683be99382785725295111> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libSparseBLAS.dylib
0x1a7ebf000 - 0x1a7f19fff libvMisc.dylib arm64  <bc70159cdf0e3898a103465d9b005d36> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvMisc.dylib
0x1a7f1a000 - 0x1a7f48fff libBNNS.dylib arm64  <eb84695115b436b0bc094c2093447946> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBNNS.dylib
0x1a7f49000 - 0x1a7f5dfff libLinearAlgebra.dylib arm64  <20ba3f17bfc0399bb11c86ba2229eb39> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLinearAlgebra.dylib
0x1a7f5e000 - 0x1a7f62fff libQuadrature.dylib arm64  <f28bbbb64cec3491afa2b8e612bcb6c9> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libQuadrature.dylib
0x1a7f63000 - 0x1a7fd1fff libSparse.dylib arm64  <115f63580cd03880bd3532006327fc91> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libSparse.dylib
0x1a7fd2000 - 0x1a8062fff libvDSP.dylib arm64  <7e74fa8ecbaf3facb1ac7c3e5b7b2843> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib
0x1a8063000 - 0x1a8063fff vecLib arm64  <a1abbd2b223933ba966abab8ce22b3be> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib
0x1a8064000 - 0x1a8064fff Accelerate arm64  <17b91b414a5c3add8f30fe76901ab19a> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate
0x1a8065000 - 0x1a807cfff libcompression.dylib arm64  <14d85278114631f8b8384811ef3ba90d> /usr/lib/libcompression.dylib
0x1a807d000 - 0x1a8621fff CoreGraphics arm64  <d0efda4febfd32be87af4ca6191fa356> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
0x1a86e6000 - 0x1a86e6fff MobileCoreServices arm64  <84949e37138737c488acfe4d81f23634> /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
0x1a8cca000 - 0x1a8d38fff BaseBoard arm64  <345238425f6d348c8cce0c59797c54dd> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BaseBoard.framework/BaseBoard
0x1a8d39000 - 0x1a8d4efff AssertionServices arm64  <bf3871acff283785bbbc9556abf09265> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssertionServices.framework/AssertionServices
0x1a8dbb000 - 0x1a8e36fff libTelephonyUtilDynamic.dylib arm64  <d77edc67ae16313fb8ac305524407770> /usr/lib/libTelephonyUtilDynamic.dylib
0x1a8e37000 - 0x1a8e55fff ProtocolBuffer arm64  <91032fdf155b3f87924a7525285f16e4> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProtocolBuffer.framework/ProtocolBuffer
0x1a8e56000 - 0x1a8e85fff MobileKeyBag arm64  <6dededb77a1e357e8f9e0e4a4637cd8b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileKeyBag.framework/MobileKeyBag
0x1a8f7e000 - 0x1a8f98fff CommonUtilities arm64  <f463a608c90b36f38c8e0cf12e59dd80> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CommonUtilities.framework/CommonUtilities
0x1a92cf000 - 0x1a92d6fff libcupolicy.dylib arm64  <5ddf224db5933b6eac3ee6d462ddb6dc> /usr/lib/libcupolicy.dylib
0x1a92d7000 - 0x1a93aafff CoreTelephony arm64  <7faa89592ffa35f5a0b4d1c6e517552a> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony
0x1a9438000 - 0x1a9469fff PersistentConnection arm64  <9bf92b0151753e6497f8d56bbb89430c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PersistentConnection.framework/PersistentConnection
0x1ac009000 - 0x1ac02afff PlugInKit arm64  <84fb63c398903b8daef3e6eabcb7cd3a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PlugInKit.framework/PlugInKit
0x1b1869000 - 0x1b1873fff CaptiveNetwork arm64  <05f935a367443dfa8d0fc4db050923ff> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CaptiveNetwork.framework/CaptiveNetwork
0x1b1874000 - 0x1b18a3fff EAP8021X arm64  <2e3f4aa248ed3dce99b8c8141e52491f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/EAP8021X.framework/EAP8021X
0x1b18a4000 - 0x1b18e1fff MobileWiFi arm64  <d6f0fe1cdd663e85947bd313450fc1fb> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileWiFi.framework/MobileWiFi
0x1b1f38000 - 0x1b1f52fff UserManagement arm64  <ef616c679dd638f4b84fd9983e30d117> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UserManagement.framework/UserManagement
0x1b1f64000 - 0x1b1f94fff Bom arm64  <1a5601365b253bc0a0d1893bf2ad8c6f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Bom.framework/Bom
0x1b20a3000 - 0x1b20b1fff libnetworkextension.dylib arm64  <14e17d913a403f0f816367fbd3299933> /usr/lib/libnetworkextension.dylib
0x1b2e2f000 - 0x1b2fccfff NetworkExtension arm64  <a360f71b21f13967b1d02e7970fe2cfe> /System/Library/Frameworks/NetworkExtension.framework/NetworkExtension
0x1b4e00000 - 0x1b4e06fff MobileSystemServices arm64  <fcadece1491f35689cc8bcc4e6dd4eaf> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileSystemServices.framework/MobileSystemServices
0x1b7896000 - 0x1b78bafff MobileInstallation arm64  <e22a9f03f3d43664bb2b47370178ddd7> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileInstallation.framework/MobileInstallation
0x1cee89000 - 0x1cefc6fff CoreServices arm64  <1b1fdbf45e42320b9f1f6bfa618a9e18> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/CoreServices
0x1cf036000 - 0x1cf15cfff Network arm64  <02086028934236b895b241a7d872034a> /System/Library/Frameworks/Network.framework/Network

EOF
```

The only part of this trace that looks remotely useful to me is in lines 3-5 of "Last Exception Backtrace", where `NSExtensionContextVendor` is started with `_beginRequestWithExtensionItems`. This makes sense, because the app crashes when it attempts to configure the device VPN to use the custom provider that I wrote. So far I've assumed that my app can see `CustomTunnel`, since that is where the crash is coming from.

Any thoughts on what might be going on here or a next step I might take to discover it?

Comment: I am facing the same issue, have double-checked all the entries and entitlements. Can you let me know how you resolved this issue?